# VB .net key not found. But it is found in dictionary. What am I missing?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

[image]

This is pretty much self explanatory. But I'll explain anyway:

I create a dictionary:

```
' import part
Imports System.Collections.Generic

'module declarations
Public Event_Conf As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)

'sub
Event_Conf("intro line") = ""

' here's the drama
WelcomeForm.Heading1.Text = Event_Conf("intro line")    'key not found.
```

So i'm checking the variable's content in the debugger, and i see 3 keys, one of the is totally a string called "intro line"! WOA! Everything is in lowercase letters, no funny characters.

What have I done wrong (besides choosing .NET for this project, i mean) ?

**Edit:**
something is screwed badly

```
WelcomeForm.Heading1.Text = "x"
```

returns exactly the same error.

- heading1 is a label control on welcomeform.
- visual basic express 2008
- windows 7 64bit

I restarted visual studio (it did miracles back in the 90s), but the same error came back.

**Edit2**:
the inner exception looks the same
[image: more details, and inner exception]

Comment: Obviously, what's going on with the WelcomeForm?  Is that the name of the class or the variable?  If this is all in the form, then try `Me.Heading1.Text = "x"`

Comment: Which control is heading1? Is this on Load() Sub? Take note the error is "creating the form", so the debugger fails on the next IL. I think the error is before that line.

Comment: What does the inner exception say?

Comment: @lars: welcomeform is a form. Maybe the error is because that form was not yet loaded?

Comment: @Gojira: attached to the original question.

Comment: @Ower" before that there are several filesystem actions, nothing with a Dictionary. The form was not loaded at this point.

Comment: What happens if you try and get the value out of the dictionary like this:         Dim txt As String
        If Event_Conf.TryGetValue("intro line", txt) Then
            Console.WriteLine("intro line = " + txt)
        End If

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but I nearly sure that VB won't let you change the label's text if the form wasn't loaded. In my case I'll override the Show() Sub of the target form and pass the Dictonary as a parameter. The error is not in the dictionary but the way you are loading the form.

Comment: Please post the _exact_ exception with stack trace that you are getting.  If possible, create a short, but complete program that duplicates the error.